# Spark cluster "round robin" load in yarn

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, benchmarking

I am doing a benchmark on a Spark job. During the first Stage (only maps and filter) when the stage is around 50%, the load average decrease on all nodes but the there is some king of "round robin" load in my nodes: one by one the will be used (cf ganglia graphics: green, next blue, next orange, ...)

[image: ganglia screen]

Why my nodes are now used one by one during the same Stage ? Is it because my RAM is full or something like that?

The bench has the following characteristics :

- Spark 1.6 on yarn with HDFS
- 10 nodes with each 1.5TB, 60GB RAM, 16 cores
- 8.5TB  of data (replication 1)

Thanks